# Bottom Up Heap in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, arraylist, heap

So, im trying to implement the bottomupheap algorithm here:
http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Classes/Notes/Felikson/courses/605202/lectures/L8/L8.html

```
Algorithm bottomUpHeap(S)
Input: a sequence S storing 2h-1 keys
Output: a heap H storing the keys in S
if S is empty then
    return an empty heap
remove the first key, k, from S
Split S into subsequences S1 and S2, each of size (n-1)/2
H1¬ bottomUpHeap(S1)
H2¬ bottomUpHeap(S2)
Create binary tree H such with k at root, H1 at left subtree and H2 at right subtree
Perform down-heap bubbling from root if necessary
return H
```

It's been a while since I programmed in java and I keep getting some errors unknown to me. I was wondering if someone would help me out by clearing up some of the algorithm steps.

I created a Heap node with data and left and right reference pointers (or whatever java calls them). The input sequence is an array which gets converted to `ArrayList`. Thats what I pass into the function above.

I remove the first key from S and create a new node with that key. In my example, I'm just using `Integer`s and the key is set to the data reference.

I then use
`S1 = S.sublist(0, S.length/2)`
and
`S2 = S.sublist(S.length/2, S.length)`

Now I would assume H1 and H2 are heaps or nodes? This is where i get a little confused on what I should do in java.

Then for the next portion it looks like I should do `k.left = H1` and `k.right = H2`

Im not really sure when it says "k at root". Isn't `k` the root node? If thats the case would I do a down-heap bubble from `k` as well? Then at the very end would `H` be `k` at this point as well?

Sorry that I don't have my code on me to post, but the errors I get are at the sublist on the recursion call.

---

### Updated:

An `ArrayList` is passed as S. `Tree` is defined as `Tree(data, left, right)`. Thanks.

```
private Tree Heapify(List<Integer> S){

    if (S.isEmpty()){
        Tree emptyHeap = new Tree();
        return emptyHeap;
    }
    
    int tmpk = S.get(0);
    S.remove(0);
    
    int halfArr = S.size()/2;

    List<Integer> S1 = S.subList(0, halfArr);
    List<Integer> S2 = S.subList(halfArr, S.size());
    
    Tree k = new Tree(tmpk, Heapify(S1), Heapify(S2));

    //Downheap.
    return null;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i would assume H1 and H2 are heaps or nodes?

The first page of your lecture notes says this:

> *"A heap is a binary tree H that stores a collection of keys at its internal nodes ..."*
>
> This is where i get a little confused on what i should do in java.

There is more than one way to do this, but the obvious representation is a Tree class that has a value, and references for the left and right subtrees.

> Im not really sure when it says k at root. Isn't k the root node?

It is the root of the heap created by the current call to `bottomUpHeap`.  Note that the algorithm is recursive!

> If thats the case would i do a down-heap bubble from k as well? Then at the very end would H be k at this point as well?

That's what it says.

> I don't have my code on me to post but the errors i get are at the sublist on the recursion call.

We cannot help much unless you post the code and the errors.

Comment: Yea, so thats what i have. Ill have to post my code when i can. Thanks.